# How to get tag url of Adsense for video (AFV)

Tags: android, tags, ads, adsense, exoplayer

I have integrated IMA SDK with Exoplayer to show video ads from Adsense.

I am able to show ads using the below test tag URL in exoplayer.
https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=640x480&iu=/124319096/external/single_ad_samples&ciu_szs=300x250&impl=s&gdfp_req=1&env=vp&output=vast&unviewed_position_start=1&cust_params=deployment%3Ddevsite%26sample_ct%3Dlinear&correlator=

Now I have created the Adsense account as per google documentation.

I am unable to find the  "**Apply for AdSense for Video**"

As per Google documentation, one has to apply for Adsense for video(AFV).
https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1705823

1. Sign in to your AdSense account.
2. Click Ads.
3. Click Other products.
4. Click Apply for AdSense for Video, and follow the steps in the interactive guide.

I am unable to find **Other products** in the Adsense account.

My aim here is shown to video ads in exoplayer

1. My question here is how to apply for AFV
2. How to generate a tag URL to show production video ads from (Google) AdSense for video.

**Adsense account**
[image]

---

---

[image]

Comment: I’ve been facing to the same issue. In my case, I had seen other products > apply adsense for video button and it disappeared suddenly after clicking it.

Comment: @akash-wangalwar, Have you got any solutions for this ? I mean how we can generate adtag url so we can use that in our video player ?